# Problem in making connection between Geoserver and S3 AWS

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud, geoserver, geotiff

I am getting below error while connecting Geoserver to S3 AWS.

`Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: null`

[image]

[image]

Same error

Comment: Maybe use a access key pair instead of username, password? I don't know any about geoserver, but I know S3 cannot be accessed with username password

Comment: I have tried using access key and Secret access key but I am not able to do so. I am getting the same error

Comment: the s3 address is right? it is `cog://s3://..`.

Comment: Same error    Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: null

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the s3:// URL, it won't work (it should start working in GeoServer 2.21.x, to be released in March 2022).
For now, get the equivalent https URL instead.

Comment: 2.20.x  Latest version of geoserver

Comment: 2.20.x is lesser than 2.21.x (the current development series). As said, it won't work. If you really want to try out 2.21.x, grab a nightly  build of the development series here: http://geoserver.org/release/main/

Comment: Thanks a lot . I am using COG optimisation.

Comment: In version 2.23 it says:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Client is immutable when created with the builder
using:
s3://bucket_path/RASTER.tif?awsRegion=EU_WEST_1

Comment: That issue has been fixed one week ago: https://github.com/geotools/geotools/pull/4355